# Docker Failed to Initialize on Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I have an issue with running the Docker Desktop on my Windows 10 PC. After trying to run it I got an error:

> Docker failed to initialize - Docker Desktop is shutting down

I already tried reinstalling (as admin), restarting PC, restarting docker services, removing content from .../AppData/Local/Docker and .../AppData/Roaming/Docker folders, but still receiving the same error message.

Does anyone have an idea how can I fix it?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downgrade to the older version solved my issue

Comment: To ensure this answer remains useful in the future, can you specify which specific versions you downgraded from and to? That will help isolate the issue.

Comment: @JeremyCaney had the same problem and downgraded to 4.3.1, it seems to work now :).

Comment: I downgraded from 4.4.4 to 4.0.0 (since this was the current version when I first installed Docker Desktop on my PC). However, as @Bogdan says, some newer versions might help too :)

Comment: I had the same issue, I downgraded from version 4.4.4 to 4.3.1 and it started working.

Answer (score 4):

Simply local Appdata on your windows box, go to Roaming->Docker and delete the settings.json file. Restart docker and you will be fine.
Appdata can be located at this path: C:\Users\LifeIsGood\AppData\Roaming\Docker

NB. LifeisGood is my username

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me when Docker Desktop stopped working after upgrading to 4.13.1 just now.

Comment: Removing settings.json also fixed my Docker Desktop after upgrading. This should be the preferred answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try uninstalling docker and deleting

1. /Users/AppData/Local/Docker
2. /Users/AppData/Roaming/Docker
3. C:/Program Files/Docker
4. C:/ProgramData/Docker
5. Reinstalling Docker

However, what worked for me ultimately was deleting .docker in /Users folder and restarting docker.

Comment: deleting .docker in /Users folder worked for me thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I get that a lot on my laptop. I restart the "Hyper-V Host Compute Service" in Services. When that has restarted, I can start Docker Desktop.

I haven't found a permanent fix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, unfortunately, this doesn't work for me.

Comment: FWIW, on my new PC I've ditched WSL2 and Docker Desktop and gone for a plain Linux VM with Docker on it. WSL2 is neat when it works, but I had too much trouble with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while starting the "Linux container" but windows container was working fine.

After trying All the possible methods to make docker desktop work, In case that is not worked then try this one. This one worked for me.

Please make sure to use **older version** of docker desktop ( mine is 4.4)

In docker desktop,

1. Go to settings --> General --> Use the WSL 2 based engine
   Where If that check box turned On, Just Turn that **off**.